# Valores por defecto desplegable excel

Tags: excel

Estoy intentando que una columna muestre un desplegable y tenga un valor por defecto en caso de cubrirse la columna C de su respectiva fila.

Mostrando el desplegable no hay absolutamente ningún problema, pero no consigo meterle por defecto un valor de esa lista a la celda(ya que no puede ir vacía). Consigo algo parecido en celdas separadas, pero ambas validaciones (lista desplegable y valor por defecto) deben estar en la misma celda.

Comment: No se puede hacer lo que quieres, salvo con macros. Necesitarías una macro que se activase cuando se cubra la columna C, que complete la celda del desplegable. Solo con fórmulas no se puede.

Answer (score 0):

En este caso tienes dos opciones:

1. En lugar de crear una validación de datos mediante lista, puedes asignar a ese rango fórmulas que validen los valores y que a la vez tomen el valor por defecto, por ejemplo con un "si" anidado o que contenga un criterio de búsqueda por ejemplo indice(coincidir). En este caso la validación sería con Formato Condicional o haciendo que la celda devuelva una cadena de texto Ej. "Error" si el resultado se sale de la lista de valores permitidos. Si el usuario debe seleccionar manualmente el desplegable o si es estricta la selección este método no funciona, pues sería solo informativo.
2. Usar VBA, creando una macro que te permita realizar ambas cosas. Este método es mas recomendable.